# How do I put the copyright / name site in footer

Tags: 7, nodes

In the four themes I tried before choosing the one I have now, the name of my website was always featured with the copyright in the footer of my webpages, but now all it says is "Copyright © 2013, ."

Is there an easy way for me to adjust the code so it does credit the site after that comma and before the period? I'm not very familiar with code so I'd be ever so grateful for an easy way. I tried searching for the copyright sign and the year in a few pages but they didn't show up so I suspect there are other ways to describe those in code, right? :)

Comment: Do you mean http://drupal.org/project/copyright_block or php code on custom block?

Comment: I meant the php code. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, make sure your site name is stil configured correctly. You can do this by going to `yoursite.com/admin/config/system/site-information`.

If the site name is there and still does not show up, then the theme you've selected is likely not working correctly. Head over to `yoursite.com/admin/appearance` and click on 'Settings' next to the theme you're using. Browse around and see whether there are any options to set the copyright message.

Failing that, modify the message directly in the template files. You will have likely installed your theme to `/sites/all/themes/theme_name` or `/sites/default/themes/theme_name`. Browse to this folder and look for a file called `page.tpl.php` (it may be in a subdirectory). This file will likely contain the copyright message which you can change right then and there. Alternatively, the copyright message maybe in the `html.tpl.php` file, which should be in the same location as `page.tpl.php`.

Comment: I'm looking at the page.tpl.php (because all other options were indeed configured correctly) and it seems to have a correct code:  
  <div id="copyright">
    <?php if (theme_get_setting('footer_copyright')): ?>
      <?php print t('Copyright'); ?> &copy; <?php echo date("Y"); ?>, <?php print $site_name; ?>.
    <?php endif; ?>
   I tried removing some of the code and adding the site name (I know, silly), but it still shows up without the name.

Comment: From the code above, the site name should be printing out from the `$site_name;` variable, but it looks like it must be empty. Try replacing `<?php print $site_name; ?>` with your site name (ex. `Claudi's Blog`) and see what happens.  And of course, double check that the `page.tpl.php` you're editing is in the theme folder for the theme that's currently active.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution which might work for you and doesn't require codework: In the admin menu, select "Structure > Blocks", then add a new block and in the Block body type in the footer text you want, and save. Then in the main Blocks page assign your new block to the "Footer" region. Only downside to this you'll have to update the copyright date once a year :)

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to use that tip for now until I'll be able to change any code haha! :D

Comment: When you're ready to venture into coding, create a module and in it create your footer programmatically for example:
`function my_module_block_info() {    
  $blocks['my_footer'] = array(
    'info' => t('My Footer'),
 'cache' => DRUPAL_NO_CACHE,
 'region' => 'Footer',
 'status' => 1, 
  );
  return $blocks;
}

function my_module_block_view($delta = '') {
  switch ($delta) {
    case 'my_footer':
 $markup = 'Copyright &copy; ' . strftime ("%Y") .' MY NAME</span>'; 
  $block['content'] = $markup;
  break;
  }
  return $block;
}`
Then assign "My Footer" block to the Footer region in Blocks menu.